# DHCP options field

Tags: dhcp, rfc

I have a problem understanding the description of the Pad-Option field of DHCP in RFC 1533:

```
3.1. Pad Option

   The pad option can be used to cause subsequent fields to align on
   word boundaries.

   The code for the pad option is 0, and its length is 1 octet.

    Code
   +-----+
   |  0  |
   +-----+
```

What does that mean? A word is 16 Bits long but why should I want to fill the rest with Pad Bytes? What does "align" even mean? Also do I have to use the Pad-Option or is it optional?
What is it for and do I have to use it?
RFC 1533: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1533

Also RFC 2131 (DHCP) states:

```
The 'options' field is now variable length. A DHCP client must be
   prepared to receive DHCP messages with an 'options' field of at least
   length 312 octets.  This requirement implies that a DHCP client must
   be prepared to receive a message of up to 576 octets, the minimum IP
```

When the client must be prepared to receive at least 312 Bytes of Optional fields, does that also mean it HAS TO create a DHCP Optional Field with minimum length of 312 Bytes? And if so, is the pad-field used to fill the rest until it reaches the 312 Bytes?
When examining packets in Wireshark I have also seen Option Fields with a length of only 60 Bytes. Does the magic cookie also count as part of the option field because it is not described as a own part of the message in the DHCP Structure in RFC 2131.

Comment: "When the client must be prepared to receive at least 312 Bytes of Optional fields, does that also mean it HAS TO create a DHCP Optional Field with minimum length of 312 Bytes?" No. Its just requirement to be prepared that options can be that long. If your DHCP server doesn't include any options he will not fill this field with 312 bytes.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for also explaining where to post this questions, I appreciate it because often it is just marked as off-topic but not explained where it would be right to post the question.

Comment: We aim to please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to fixed-length option fields (which automatically align the next field), there are variable-length option fields that may have a 16-bit or 32-bit field behind them. Since those fields require alignment you can pad the packet with the Pad-Option field.

> 3.1. Pad Option
>
> The pad option can be used to cause subsequent fields to align on
> word boundaries.
>
> The code for the pad option is 0, and its length is 1 octet.
>
> ```
> Code    +-----+    |  0  |    +-----+
> ```

[RFC 2132](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132)

Comment: So that means that the Pad-Option field is normally used in between some options? It is weird that in all packets I have captured it is only used at the very end of the dhcp message.

Comment: Well, the pad field code is `0`, so any zeros at the end are pad fields... Note that the minimum Ethernet SDU is 46 bytes which also may need padding.